# How to move to the last point position before popping mark-ring?

Tags: emacs

I often come to below scenario:

Assumptions:
I have 5 marks in total:  current mark is at position `5`, and 4 marks on mark-ring at positions: `4`,`3`,`2`,`1` respectively. My point location is somewhere far away, say, `100`.

Situation:
Now I found an error at `4`, so I <kbd>C-u C-SPC</kbd> to jump to position `4` and fixed it. But I forget to save the previous point position `100`. How do I jump back?

I understand that one good practice is to save the point position before jump. But similar jumps happens very frequently and in times the problem happens 1 or 2 times. Once it happens, it will be nice if there could be a remedy to it, since it seems a special position too, (last point position before popping mark-ring).

Without a remedy, it seems a painful trip to manually go from position `4` to `100` manually, even it happens in a low frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code adds the current position of point to the mark-ring
when you invoke <kbd>C-u C-SPC</kbd> and lets you cycle through
previous items in the mark ring using <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> (instead of
<kbd>C-u C-SPC</kbd>):

```lisp
(setq set-mark-command-repeat-pop t)

(defadvice set-mark-command (before record-current-position (arg) activate)
  (when arg (push-mark)))
```

#### Explanation

The [advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) defined above tells Emacs to call the `push-mark` function `before` executing the body of the `set-mark-command` command (but only if `set-mark-command` was called with a prefix `arg`).

`push-mark` adds the current position of mark to the mark ring and sets mark to the current position of point.

By setting `set-mark-command-repeat-pop` to a non-`nil` value we are telling Emacs to keep popping the mark when hitting <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> right after hitting <kbd>C-u C-SPC</kbd>.

#### Visual Example

Based on the example you gave I am including a visualization of a full "round trip" below, where:

- `x` : head of mark ring
- `^` : location of mark
- `|` : location of point

<sub>I'm including this example for completeness. If you don't care about what exactly is going on with point, mark, and positions in the mark ring behind the scenes, you can stop reading now :)</sub>

---

1. Situation *before* hitting <kbd>C-u C-SPC</kbd>:

   ```
   1 2 3 4 5 ... 100
         x ^      |
   ```
2. Situation *after* hitting <kbd>C-u C-SPC</kbd>.

   - After Emacs has evaluated body of `advice` defined above:

     ```
     1 2 3 4 5 ... 100
             x      ^
                    |
     ```

     As you can see, the previous location of mark (`5`) has been pushed onto the mark ring, and mark is at the current location of point (`100`).
   - After Emacs has evaluated body of advised command (`set-mark-command`):

     ```
     1 2 3 4 5 ... 100
           x ^      |
     ```

     The mark has been popped; since it was at `100` before, point remains at that location. Mark is at `5` again.
3. Situation after hitting <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> for the first time:

   ```
   1 2 3 4 5 ... 100
       x ^ |
   ```
4. Locations of `a`, `^`, and `|` on subsequent invocations of <kbd>C-SPC</kbd>:

   ```
   1 2 3 4 5 ... 100
     x ^ |

   1 2 3 4 5 ... 100
   x ^ |

   1 2 3 4 5 ... 100
   ^ |            x

   1 2 3 4 5 ... 100
   |       x      ^

   1 2 3 4 5 ... 100
         x ^      |
   ```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of possibilities.

One is to get into the habit of using `exchange-point-and-mark` (C-x C-x).

Another is to advice `pop-to-mark-command`, so that is pushes (and pops) the mark before moving, e.g. (using the new advice system):

```
(defun save-mark-before-pop ()
  (push-mark (point) t)
  (pop-mark))

(advice-add 'pop-to-mark-command :before 'save-mark-before-pop)
```

This will still require you to go through the whole `mark-ring` but it should be enough of a remedy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a elisp to do it.

[point-undo.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/point-undo.el)

You can undo and redo point even if you forget to mark point. It's very useful.